# MS Word Insert hyperlink to heading of same name

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document with about 200 subtitles at the "Heading 2" style level and approaching a thousand pages. In addition to the table of contents, there's a table that links to different headings and I was wondering what's the fastest way to hyperlink to the headings without going through the entire Word hyperlink dialogue provided the text between the heading and the text I want to link to go there are exactly the same.

Example:

```
Table of Contents
Introduction
Dogs
    blah blah blah
Cats
    blah blah blah
Cows
    blah blah blah
Link Stuff
    blah Dogs blah Cats blah Cows
```

And I would like the Dogs, Cats, and Cows to link to the Headings for the appropriate section. Going through the entire word dialogue for hyperlinking is quite cumbersome for 200+ links.

I've tried adding the words HYPERLINK \l Dogs and then going Ctrl+F9 and then F9 but then that links me to the Table of Contents. If I do HYPERLINK \l _Dogs then it links me to beginning of document.

One quick note, I do know about copying a hyperlinked text and the find/replacing it with ^c from clipboard, but my problem is not I need 1 hyperlink copy pasted all over my document but rather I need 200 different hyperlinks to headings that share the same text.

Any solution that's easily macroable would be great since searching through the entire document structure with the traditional hyperlinking dialogue through ctrl+k cannot be macro'd very easily.